# Using Sqoop to import data from teradata to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I have to pull out schema of tables in teradata, but i do not have the permissions to the tables. is it possible to fetch metadata by sqoop without the select access?

Comment: Question is not clear. If you do not have permissions on tables, how can you pull the the tables? What you want to do by pulling metadata alone?

Comment: i want to add my own random data instead of actual data. I am able to pull the schema and create the same in hive using scoop on tables where i have permissions. but wanted to check if the same can be done for tables where i don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop or any tool would require you to have access to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to access DBC.TABLES which contains much of the metadata you're looking for. If you do not have access to some tables, you may not have access to DBC either, however.